# Generating an image - The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, image

I'm using the code below to display an image that shows text of how many users are connected to my site.  I replaced the image that I was using 'vad.png' with a different one.  Now I'm getting the error "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Anyone know how I can fix this?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM server_status"); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); 
$text = "Online"; 
$image = imagecreatefrompng('vad.png'); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 10, 0, 0);
if (strlen($row['users_online']) >= 3){ 
imagefttext($image, 11, 0, 435, 38, $black, './verdana.ttf', $row['users_online']); 
}
else
{
imagefttext($image, 11, 0, 440, 38, $black, './verdana.ttf', $row['users_online']); 
}
imagefttext($image, 8, 0, 432, 55, $black, './verdana.ttf', $text); // Remove the // ahead of this line to use it 
header('Content-type: image/png'); 
imagepng($image); 
imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: you cold do this with text and css, why use an image in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Comment the `header('Content-type: image/png');` and call the script from browser. Check for messages that might appear before the garbage related to the image itself.

You may need to add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script in case error reporting/display is turned off as well.

Comment: @user1123513  So, what did you get? `The image contains errors` means that there is something else that was sent to the browser together with image content, probably. Typically these are error messages from the script. Call the script directly from the browser with required parameters, not the page that contains `img` tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once when  I had accidentally transferred over some  0 byte image cache files from one server to another.  You may want to check that out, it could be a invalid cache file or   it can't overwrite it even.

Here is a blog post where I wrote about this.
http://www.daxmax.com/index.php/2012/03/20/wordpresstimthumb-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contained-errors/

Answer (score 0):

I've  found that when I've uploaded some files to web server, they won't display and mozilla show information about errors in file...

The problem was caused by transfer type in filezilla, it should be BINARY or AUTO, not ASCII.
that was my solution for my problem, maybe it would be helpfull for someone